# Excel VBA file already open error When It's not - Mac Office

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to write a macro code for an excel file I'm working on (In Office 2016 for Mac).

The code consist of 2 parts:
1. A Workbook_SheetChange listener which when certain cells change, will trigger a function that opens a csv file, reads it, and then manipulates it according to how I want it to. This part works fine. 
2. A button that needs to read from the same csv file mentioned and change cells in the workbook according to it. It was working until I've added the above functionality.

Now, when I press the button to read from the csv, an error jumps of "file already open" and when I press debug to see where it fails, it refers me to the function in the sheet changed macro (which shouldn't be triggered at all).

The read function is:

```
Private Sub ReadCSV_Click()
Dim serial As String
Dim signer As String
loc_idx = -1
Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path + "/test.csv"
Open FilePath For Input As #1
row_number = 0

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, LineFromFile
    LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
    signer = Replace(LineItems(0), Chr(34), vbNullString) 'Location
    If Not signer = vbNullString Then
        serial = Replace(CStr(LineItems(1)), Chr(34), vbNullString) 'SN
        Call SearchCell(serial) 'Search the SN
        Call SearchLocationCol(f_ws_idx) 'Search Location column in the relevant sheet
        Worksheets(f_ws_idx).Cells(f_row, loc_idx).Value = signer
    End If
    row_number = row_number + 1
Loop

Close #1
MsgBox "Done Updating"
```

End Sub

And the Listener function is:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
        If Not Sh.Name = "Macros" Then
            Call InsertChange("test", "1111")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub InsertChange(n_loc As String, n_ser As String)
        Dim LineFromFile As String
        Dim LineItems() As String
        Dim split_new_csv() As String
        Dim is_new As Boolean
        Dim serial_changed As String
        Dim location_changed As String
        Dim new_csv_str As String
        Dim signer As String
        Dim serial As String
        Dim row_number As Integer
        Dim rec As Variant
        Dim rec_item As Variant
        is_new = True
        new_csv_str = ""
        serial_changed = n_ser
        location_changed = n_loc

        Dim FilePath As String
        FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path + "/test.csv"

        Dim FilePathTemp As String
        Dim scriptstr As String

        scriptstr = "return posix path of (path to desktop folder) as string"

        FilePathTemp = MacScript(scriptstr) + "s.csv"
        Open FilePath For Input As #1
            row_number = 0
            Do Until EOF(1) 'Go Through all of the lines in the csv
                Line Input #1, LineFromFile
                LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
                signer = Replace(LineItems(0), Chr(34), vbNullString) 'Location
                If Not signer = vbNullString Then
                    serial = Replace(CStr(LineItems(1)), Chr(34), vbNullString) 'SN
                    If serial = serial_changed Then
                        is_new = False
                        signer = location_changed
                    End If
                    new_csv_str = new_csv_str + signer + "," + serial + "\n"
                    row_number = row_number + 1
                End If
            Loop
        Close #1

        MsgBox "Done updating"
        End Sub
```

Yes, the code needs a clean-up, but the debug error refers me to:

```
Open FilePath For Input As #1
```

In the listener code, while it shouldn't be activated at all. I've tried to change variable names, even to create a duplicate in the listener and to work with it as other file, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to solve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that an event retriggers the execution of worksheet_change. I would disable the events when entering insertchange. However the code you posted doesn't seem to interact with the worksheet.

```
Public Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
        If Not Sh.Name = "Macros" Then
            application.enableevents=False
            Call InsertChange("test", "1111")
            application.enableevents=true
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That seems to trigger the ReadCell function correctly.